# JQgrid: Formatter with a custom delete button?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I'm working with Jqgrid and (with you help) I made this formatter:

```
function editarFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    var cellValue = cellvalue;
    var url="<a href='editar_equipo.php?equi_id=" + cellValue + "'><img src='images/edit_icon.gif' alt='" + cellValue + "' title='Editar: " + cellValue + "' />Editar</a>";
    url+="<a href='eliminar.php?equi_id=" + cellValue + "'><img src='images/trash.png' alt='" + cellValue + "' title='Eliminar: " + cellValue + "' />Eliminar</a>";

    return url;
};
```

What return this as a column for each row:

[image: JQgrid formatter example]

The "Editar" (Edit) Button redirects without problem to another .php page with a form that edits the info of that row.

But for the Delete button, I don't wanna redirect to another page. Instead, I want a dialog where ask me if I want to delete that row, with "Yes" and "No" options, just like the delete button from the "Actions" Formatter.

I already saw [How can I implement a custom jqGrid delete button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119510/jqgrid-custom-delete-button) and [Custom delete button in jqGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360550/custom-delete-button-in-jqgrid), But can't figure out how apply them to the link whit icon of my formatter.

Any help will be apreciated! :)
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can for example use `href` in the `<a>` of your custom formatter and use `onCellSelect` callback to execute any action on the user click on the button. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5305904/315935) for more details.

Alternatively you can use `onclick` attribute of the `<a>` to start any JavaScript which will be executed if the user click on the link. You can look at the code of [dynamicLink](https://github.com/OlegKi/jqGrid-plugins/blob/master/jQuery.jqGrid.dynamicLink.js) formatter (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9048483/315935)) to see how you can implement this.

Comment: Thank you so much, Oleg!
I tried with the "onclick" solution and worked quite well.